# Laravel 5 - maximum supervisord processes to avoid mysql error "error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded"

Tags: mysql, laravel, supervisord

I am using laravel 5.2 and I have created a task schedule at 1am to do below process:

1. Get all users (currently around 250 users)
2. For each user, I created a job (will be executed by queue), which will add users' tasks. Normally 10 task for each user. below is my handle() method for the command class.

   ```
   public function handle()
   {
       // get all users
       $users = User::all();

       $this->info(count($users) . ' total users');

       // schedule user tasks in queue
       foreach ($users as $user) {
           $job = new ScheduleUserTask($user);
           $this->bus->dispatch($job);
       }
   }
   ```

Then the job will check users task and insert into tasks table. 
I am using database connection as the queue with supervisord.

My supervisord's worker configuration

```
[program:mytask-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/myproject/artisan queue:work database --sleep=1 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=user2
numprocs=4
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/myproject/worker.log
```

Previously when I run supervisor with 1 process (numprocs), it works nicely. However when I start increase the process to 4, I start getting error bellow.

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction (SQL:
>   insert into `jobs` (`queue`, `attempts`, `reserved`, `reserved_at`,
>   `available_at`, `created_at`, `payload`) values ..

From my understanding, this caused by multiple processes / threads running to insert the queue and locking the table.

My question is, what is the maximum number of process that I can run for supervisord regarding my case?

Is it good to increase the `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get this error when you run queue:work or when you run your console command? Judging from the error, it cannot enqueue the job (and supervisor is fetching existing jobs - SELECT/UPDATE queries, not inserts)

Comment: I got this when run console command. so this error appear while executing the command

Comment: @DenisMysenko I just added my worker configuration